# How to create a parent > child collection with laravel based on an eloquent result?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-8

Basically I have a eloquent result like this.

```
    99 => {#2033
          +"rule_id": 2
          +"user_id": 1
          +"url_id": 50
          +"operator": "<="
          +"value": "3"
          +"id": 2
          +"titre": "Temps de réponse"
          +"description": "Description 2"
          +"actived": 1
          +"type": "float"
          +"unit": "seconde(s)"
          +"created_at": "2022-01-24 18:58:45"
          +"updated_at": "2022-01-24 18:58:45"
          +"category_id": 2
        }
    100 => {#2034
          +"rule_id": 1
          +"user_id": 1
          +"url_id": 51
          +"operator": "="
          +"value": "Indexable"
          +"id": 1
          +"titre": "Indexable"
          +"description": "Description 1"
          +"actived": 1
          +"type": "bool"
          +"unit": null
          +"created_at": "2022-01-24 18:58:45"
          +"updated_at": "2022-01-24 18:58:45"
          +"category_id": 1
        }
    101 => {#2035
          +"rule_id": 2
          +"user_id": 1
          +"url_id": 51
          +"operator": "<="
          +"value": "3"
          +"id": 2
          +"titre": "Temps de réponse"
          +"description": "Description 2"
          +"actived": 1
          +"type": "float"
          +"unit": "seconde(s)"
          +"created_at": "2022-01-24 18:58:45"
          +"updated_at": "2022-01-24 18:58:45"
          +"category_id": 2
        }
```

For each line, I need to do a test to output a verification result (comparison of "operator" and "value" with the raw result of checkRule($url_id, ..) ) which I run at each turn of the loop.

I need to turn into a parent-child collection of this type

```
rules [
  0 [
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'rule 1',
    'check_ok' => 
      [
      0 => [
          'address' => 'http://www...',
          'operator' => '<='
          'excepted' => '10'
          'obtained' => '1'    
         ],
      1 ...
      ]
    'check_nok' => 
      [
      0 => [
          'address' => 'http://www...',
          'operator' => '<='
          'excepted' => '11'
          'obtained' => '15'    
         ],
      1 ...
  ],
  1 .... //rule 2
]
```

Then I could go into blade and send an email of the checkup.

Is this possible? If so how?
I have tried everything but have not succeeded.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

as i know you must use api resource class to change output of eloquent

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.
However, my question is mainly about the methodology/algorithm.

I can't obtain what I want with the ->push(), ->put(), I must be using them wrong.

Thanks